# Automatic Visual Studio Nuget consolidatation

Tags: powershell, visual-studio

I'm hoping to automate the 'Manage Nuget Packages for Solution' Consolidate User Interface using Powershell in the 'Package Manager Console'.

The following script should take ONE of the packages in the consolidation list and 'fix it'.

```
#do just one
get-package | Group-Object Id | foreach { [pscustomobject]@{ packagename=$_.Name; VG=$_.Group ;versions=($_.Group |select -expandproperty versions |select -ExpandProperty Version); versionMAX=($_.Group |select -expandproperty versions |select -ExpandProperty Version |sort -property versions -descending |select -last 1)  } } | foreach { [pscustomobject]@{ packagename=$_.packagename; VG=$_.VG; versions=$_.versions; versionCount= $_.versions.Count; versionMAX=$_.versionMAX }} | where versionCount -gt 1 | foreach { [pscustomobject]@{ packagename=$_.packagename; VG=$_.VG; versions=$_.versions; versionMAX=$_.versionMAX; dversions=($_.versions | select -Unique) }} | foreach { [pscustomobject]@{ packagename=$_.packagename; VG=$_.VG; versionMAX=$_.versionMAX; PN=$_.VG.ProjectName; versions=$_.versions; dversionCount=$_.dversions.Count }} | where dversionCount -gt 1 | select -first 1 | foreach { foreach($v in $_.VG) { update-package -Id $v.Id -Version $_.versionMAX -projectname $v.ProjectName } }
```

Comment: `versionMAX = ($_.Group |select -expandproperty versions |select -ExpandProperty Version |sort -property versions -descending |select -last 1)`  Is that not a bug?  Sort the versions from Z to A, then get the last item and assign it to `versionMAX`?  Also, keep in mind that Version is a string and will use string sorting, so version `10.2` is less than version `9.5`

Comment: @BaconBits I thought it was a bug too!  but using select -first 1 was giving me the lowest version.  Maybe its the -descending in front of it ??

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Select-Object` instead of casting to pscustomobjects. For instance this:

```
foreach { [pscustomobject]@{ packagename=$_.packagename; VG=$_.VG; versions=$_.versions; versionCount= $_.versions.Count; versionMAX=$_.versionMAX }}
```

becomes this, which is somewhat shorter and less noisy:

```
select packagename VG versions @{Name="versionCount"; Exp={$_.versions.Count}} versionMAX
```

Notice the calculated property for `versionCount`.

Regarding the single line of code, I think you could have multiple statements separated by semicolons. You would work on the code as multiple lines in your text editor, and then join them together before pasting into VS.

```
Write-Output hello; Write-Output world
```

Comment: does the Exp field have special meaning?   I was having problems without the cast to pscustomobject.

Comment: @BozoJoe It's a calculated property.  It's a special hashtable to create a property with `Select-Object` and some other cmdlets.  It has two elements: `Name`(or `Label`) and `Expression`.  They can be abbreviated all the way down to a single character:  `@{n='Name';e={$_.Value}}`.  You can also specify the column's width with `Width` with `Format-Table`.  See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692794.aspx).

Comment: @BozoJoe, `Exp` can contain any PowerShell expression. For instance if you wanted `packagename` to be in uppercase, then you could do `Exp={$_.packagename.ToUpper()}`. I used in the code above because this won't work: `select versions.Count`.